# How to use GCC's I-flag to include multiple folders?

Tags: gcc, makefile, include, include-path

Normally I use GCC's I-flag to include folders in this way:

```
gcc main.c -IfolderA -IfolderB
```

Well I need to reorganize my makefiels structure and I'm thinking about to have an environment variable which is defined as this:

```
INCLUDES="folderA folderB"
```

How could I use GCC's I-flag to include both folders?

I thought about something (but it does not work) like this:

```
gcc main.c -I($(INCLUDES))
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the `-I` flag to all the "elements" of your `INCLUDES` variable. Perhaps through something like this:

```
gcc main.c $(foreach dir,$(INCLUDES),-I$(dir))
```

[The `foreach` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Foreach-Function.html#Foreach-Function).

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the [`addprefix` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html#File-Name-Functions) -- although it's designed to work on filenames, it can still be used here:

```
gcc main.c $(addprefix -I,$(INCLUDES))
```